# Firefox extension to log out of HTTP authentication-based sites

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, http, firefox-extensions

The title says it all. does it exist? I know the webdeveloper toolbar does, but I would love something that's a bit more specific and clearly shows me in the browser I'm logged in, and a button to log out.

I searched on the add-ons site to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

how about [http-logout](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/http-logout/) addon.

Comment: would be nice if it was a bit more visual and not 'log out all http sessions'. I'll accept it as good enough though if nothing else comes up.